# Uncaught Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

Hi I am trying to build my first Angular app with Typescript but I can not seem to bind a controller correctly.

This is my typescript code:

```
module App {
   var modules: string[] = ["App.Person"];
   angular.module('App', modules)
          .run([]);
} 

module App.Person {
   angular.module('App.Person', []);
}

module App.Person {
    angular.module("App.Person")
           .controller('PersonCtrl', PersonCtrl);

    interface IPersonScope extends ng.IScope {
        fullName: string;
    }

    class PersonCtrl{
        public $scope: IPersonScope;

        static $inject = ['$scope'];
        constructor($scope: IPersonScope) {
            this.$scope = $scope;
            this.init();            
        }
        init() : void  {
            this.$scope.fullName = 'Justin S.';
        } 
    }
}
```

This is my view:

```
 <article ng-app="App">
    <section ng-controller="PersonCtrl">
        <p ng-bind="fullName"></p>
    </section>
</article>
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got undefined
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: In my experience that error gets thrown when angular expects a function where you don't provide one.  Could your ".run([ ])" (line 4) be causing this?  I think the answer from @daveoncode is pretty close.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely you might have missed to include the controller js file (ex: `<script src='path/angularController.js'></script>`) in your layout page. If this is fine, then please double check if you have multiple ng-app in your html.

Comment: This helped me in a MVC-application. I was referencing the necessary file using a <reference>-tag so Visual Studio showed no errors. However, I had forgotten to add the .js-file in the BundleConfig. Thanks!